# Align Elements that are dynamically instanced

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I'm having issues trying to align content spread across several data-templates.

I am building a flexible Forms framework that basically allows us to enter meta-data in a database, hydrate models from this meta-data and bind a collection of these models to a View. The View then uses a template selector to choose the appropriate UI element to display to the view, based on the model meta-data.

As an example, the following data-templates are a couple that I am using:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:FormField}"
              x:Key="TextBoxDataTemplate">
    <WrapPanel Margin="5 5 5 0">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
                   Margin="0 0 10 0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <formViews:TextInputUserControl />
        </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:FormField}"
              x:Key="MultiLineTextBoxDataTemplate">
    <WrapPanel Margin="5 5 5 0">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="0 0 10 0" />
        <formViews:MultiLineTextInputUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                 MinWidth="250"
                                                 MinHeight="100"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The user controls are nothing more than a text box databound to an associated view model, and some minor stuff taking place in the code-behind.

When they render to the screen, the `TextBlock` width causes the alighment to be off.

```
Description _________
User name ________
Employee Identification ______
etc.
```

The view can be sliced up in to various sections. Each section is a DockPanel that contains an ItemsControl bound to a collection of meta-data objects designated for each section.

```
------------------------------------
            Header
------------------------------------

|       |                    |      |
|       |                    |      |
|       |                    |      |
|Left   |     Body           |Right |
|       |                    |      |
|       |                    |      |

------------------------------------
            Footer
------------------------------------
```

We tried a couple of solutions.

### Solution 1: Use a Grid

Instead of a `WrapPanel` we used a `Grid`. The TextBlock was placed in column 0 and the user control in column 1. This worked, but we had to provide all elements in column 1 with a minimum width. A checkbox had to maintain the same width as a textbox, which didn't look good. If we didn't specify a minwidth, then the textbox's became 15pt wide.

We tried the Grid columns in various configurations, including shared size groups. Allowing for different element Types to have different widths caused layout issues.

Another problem with this was that we lost the nice wrapping of the elements when the view was reduced in size. If an `ItemsControl` in a section doesn't contain any items, the dockpanel collapses. We wanted the use wrap panels so that content flows right to left and fills the needed space. If the Right section has items, the body becomes constricted and flows vertical.

This was achieved by changing the itemscontrol panel to a wrap panel, and having the root container in the data-templates be a wrap panel. This worked well, with the exception of the alignment issues.

### Solution 2: Create a DisplayTextWidth view model property

We created a DisplayTextWidth property in the Windows view model. Due to the Forms framework being generic, we have several Windows & view models using this framework in different ways. We hide the view models behind an interface that required the DisplayTextWidth, then used relative path to bind each TextBlock's width to it.

```
public double DisplayTextWidth
{
    get
    {
        return this.displayTextWidth;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value > this.displayTextWidth)
        {
            this.displayTextWidth = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was that the property was always zero, and the setter never got hit. Even with the binding set to two-way.

Elsewhere in my code, I'm binding TextBlocks width to the widest textblock element in the view:

```
<Label Content="Category:"
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ContractorLabel}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
<ComboBox x:Name="CategoryComboBox"
            MinWidth="200"
            ItemsSource="{Binding EquipmentFilter.EquipmentCategories}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding EquipmentFilter.SelectedEquipmentCategory}"
            Margin="10 0 0 0"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

This works great and gives me a result like:

```
Employee _________
     Age _________
   Title _________
```

I can't do this with the data-templates though without a bit of work. I'm wondering if I should write a Dependency Property to walk the visual tree and set the TextBlock width to be the same across all of them, with it being the width of w/e TextBlock is widest. I could decorate the TextBlocks in the Data-Template with a Tag, and look for the Tag then assign the Width to each TextBlock to match the widest.

This seems like overkill though, is there another route to take for this?

Comment: You're probably going to need to implement a custom panel or look into something like DevExpress's [LayoutControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8147).

Comment: I won't be able to get a license to DevExpress, but I can take a look at reproducing that kind of a panel. Thanks for the input